# iOS custom font rendering issues with Umlaut glyphs

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, uilabel, custom-font

My app uses a custom font (by Linotype, i.e. a professional font). In UILabels as well as UITextViews and TextFields, composite glyphs like the German ö, ä and ü are rendered in incorrect size and weight.

I tried quite a lot from changing trying other fonts (which rendered as expected) to testing other font sizes, but always had this artifact.

Does anybody have a clue, what the problem with that font could be?

As a sidenote, the android app renders that same font just fine, which only hints that font rendering engines on the two platforms are likely different.

Here is an example (check the the ü-glyph):
[image]

Comment: iOS 11, simulator as well as device by the way.

Comment: can you provide a screen shot of the problem ? Is the top of the glyph cut ?

Comment: The glyph is not being cut, no. It turns out the string resource contained a character, which had a (hidden) attribution. It was not clear to me, that Xcode .strings files can contain formatting information like rich text, but It obviously does.

Answer (score 3):

I spent a lot of time trying to figure out the cause, but ignored the obvious: the string literal in the strings resource file was copied from another application (or a pdf I guess) and contained the composed characters in a kind of alternative way.

After **retyping the text**, which which contained odd characters, they were rendered perfectly fine!

I know it looks like I only wrote the question to answer it myself, but it  is just a happy incident that I found the cause just now while going on examining the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In case umlaut appears in the content you don't control (e.g. delivered by the backend):

#### 2 Solutions:

1. In Swift, `text.precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping` to replace all instances of this unfriendly combination with classical `\u{00FC}` represantation.
2. Use tool like [glyphrstudio](https://www.glyphrstudio.com/online/) to manually add support for Combining Diaeresis `\u{0308}`.

#### Why this happens?

Your font doesn't contain [Combining Diaeresis](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0308) character. In failing case string instead of one ü character represented by one `\u{00FC}`, consists of actually 2 characters `u` and `\u{0308}` (Combining Diaeresis), which your font doesn't support.

##### References:

- https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/stringsandcharacters/#Extended-Grapheme-Clusters
- https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel/issues/57
- https://jongampark.wordpress.com/2008/07/21/unicode-normalization-and-nsstring/